# JQuery UI Autocomplete and Google Keywords

Tags: jquery, seo

I am using [JQuery UI's autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) on a site of mine as a Country Selector and am pretty happy with the functionality. I have the country selector on pretty much every page of importance on the site as it is used to allow people to search.

The issue that I am having is that the widget is screwing up my Google Keyword density. Because the autocomplete field contains every country, and it appears on all pages, Google believes my site's major keywords include "Island" (1), with "Saint" (3), "Republic" (4) and "South" (5) following closely behind.

I think part of the problem can be fixed by placing the appearance of the country autocomplete lower in my html, but I would prefer that those words not make it into Google's scans at all.

So, my question is this: Is there a way to "hide" part of a pages content from Google? It needs to be kosher with Google as I don't want them to think I am trying to trick them and get sin-binned.

Cheers,

James.

Comment: You could probably try and store the array in JSON syntax in a .js file and fill your autocomplete field using JavaScript. This way it would require Google to execute the JavaScript on the site in order to find the keywords.

Comment: Halfdn, why not put that as an answer, I was going to answer thar

Comment: Thanks halfdan. I'll look into doing it that way. If you copy your comment into an answer I'll give you the big tick! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer this question by quoting the excellent answer provided by @halfdan in a comment on the original question. I am doing this because I want to accept an answer for this question, but can't accept a comment as the answer.

halfdan wrote on Sep 8 at 0:54:
You could probably try and store the array in JSON syntax in a .js file and fill your autocomplete field using JavaScript. This way it would require Google to execute the JavaScript on the site in order to find the keywords. – halfdan Sep 8 at 0:54